# Google Intensity API, set width issues?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization, heatmap

It seems as though I'm placing the size option in the wrong place or missing something altogether, after searching for a few hours i've now resorted to asking the obvious.

This is a Google Chart Map with some data in in but can't seem to get the map size to be 1000px wide but in aspect ratio? any help or advice would be great!

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/intensitymap is the page I'm working from.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
  google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['intensitymap']});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Country', 'Volume', 'N/A'],
        ['AF', 1009675, 0],
        ['AL', 224609, 0 ]
]
    );

    var options = {
      width: '1000'
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.IntensityMap(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, {});

 }

</script>

            <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things: Your width value should be a number not a string (without "'"). And you need to pass your option variable in when you `.draw()`. Like this:

```
var options = {
  width: 1000
};

var chart = new google.visualization.IntensityMap(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
chart.draw(data, options);
```

}

Also, apparently the max width is 440px. See [here (scroll down to configuration options)](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/intensitymap#Configuration_Options).

Comment: Thanks, indeed, it now seems that 440 is the max but its done the trick! thanks.